# How to cut Bootstrap column height to match adjacent column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following Bootstrap 4 layout, which uses two columns...

- Left column, containing three cards-in-columns
- Right column, containing a list group

The contents of the list group are longer than the contents of the three cards in the left-hand-side.

How can I use Bootstrap to limit the height of the list group's container to match the height of the adjacent column which contains three cards?

Right now, I have used CSS `max-height`, but this is not a suitable way for me to proceed.

[image]

```
    <!-- Left column -->
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-4 pb-4">
            <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay" target="_blank">
              First card is here.
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 pb-4">
          <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay" target="_blank">
            Second card is here
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 pb-4">
          <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay" target="_blank">
            Third card is here
          </a>
        </div>

      </div><!-- end .row -->

  </div><!-- end Left column -->


  <!-- Right column -->
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 d-none d-sm-block" style="max-height: 725px; overflow-y: scroll;">

     <div class="list-group list-unstyled">
      List group is here
     </div>

  </div>
```

NB. the cards use .card-img-overlay and their dimensions remain the same as those of the image used inside.

Comment: something like this probably: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48943583/8620333 .. you make the content inside out of the flow

Comment: Perhaps looking into [CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) could make it easier for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409995/bootstrap-4-row-height-set-by-specific-col-not-highest-one) you would set `overflow:auto` on the parent column and absolute position the list-group within the column.

```
  <div class="row">
        <!-- Left column -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-4 pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay py-5" target="_blank">
              First card is here.
            </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay py-5" target="_blank">
            Second card is here
          </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay py-5" target="_blank">
                        Third card is here
                      </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end .row -->
        </div>
        <!-- Right column -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 d-none d-sm-block overflow-auto">
            <div class="list-group list-unstyled scroll overflow-auto">
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/okYRFgEro5

Answer (score -1):

Contain them in one parent `div` and put height on that `div`.

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="height: 350px">
<!-- Left column -->
<div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-4 pb-4">
        <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay" target="_blank">
          First card is here.
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 pb-4">
      <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay" target="_blank">
        Second card is here
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 pb-4">
      <a href="#" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0 card-overlay" target="_blank">
        Third card is here
      </a>
    </div>

  </div><!-- end .row -->
```

```
 <div class="list-group list-unstyled">
  List group is here
 </div>

</div>
</div><!-- end parent div now -->
```

Comment: That doesn't work. And the height of the feature card is certainly more than 350px.